# How to wait in angular component while service is Fetching (with Http)and Manipulating that data and return

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I have component where I call service function

```
**xyz.component.ts**

let limitCrossed = this.outgoingPaymentsMultipleService.checkMultipleApproveLimit(selectedPayments);

    let param: DialogConfirmCallerConfig = {
      confirmationNeeded: **limitCrossed != null,** // I need to use return data here
      data: {limitFailed: {account:"user",duration:"payment"}}

    };
```

In service file xyz.service.ts

```
checkMultipleApproveLimit(payments){
    combineLatest([currencyConversion$, userPaymentsLimit$]).subscribe(([c, l]) => {
      
      const limitFailed = this.isPaymentsLimitCrossed(paymentsLimitsCheck, c, l)
      
      return limitFailed;

    })

    isPaymentsLimitCrossed(paymentsLimitsCheck, currencyConversionRates, limits){
    // some calculation and base on that returning object
    
    return {o : true };
    }
```

***in component how to wait to use limitCrossed***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, your code isn't working correctly: you are returning a `subscription` from your service to your component, and you aren't subscribing to anything.

#### Service

```js
checkMultipleApproveLimit(payments){
  return combineLatest([currencyConversion$, userPaymentsLimit$]).pipe(
    map(([c, l]) => this.isPaymentsLimitCrossed(paymentsLimitsCheck, c, l))
  );
}
```

#### Component

```js
    let param: DialogConfirmCallerConfig; 
    
    this.outgoingPaymentsMultipleService.checkMultipleApproveLimit(selectedPayments)
    .subscribe(limitedCrossed => )
    
        param ={
          confirmationNeeded: !limitCrossed,
          data: {limitFailed: {account:"user",duration:"payment"}}
        };
```

To understand how `Observables` works refer to [Angular observables overview](https://angular.io/guide/observables)